# Angular 2 - Click to show and hide

Tags: html, angular

I want to use a button to show and hide elements in my HTML. I know i have to use a boolean in the typescript and *ngIf in the HTML.

In my typescript i have a boolean:

```
showHide: false;
```

In my HTML i have:

```
<button (click) = "showHide=true" </button>
```

I use this to hide elements. I hide my elements with the use of *ngIf="showHide" on the elements i want to hide.

But how can i bring back the elements i have hidden with the same button?

Comment: use `<button (click) = "showHide=!showHide" </button>` if you want to toggle visibility.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this

```
<button (click)="showHide = !showHide">click</button>
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use a function to change from true to false and vice versa instead of just setting *showHide* true each time you click the button.

To do so you need to create a function e.g. *changeShowStatus* to change the value of *showHide*.

```
changeShowStatus(){
    this.showHide = !this.showHide;
  }
```

Then you call this function every time you hit the button by changing your showHide=true to changeShowStatus():

```
<button type="button" (click)="changeShowStatus()">show/hide</button>
```

To set the initial status you could set the *showHide* value in the constructor and define showHide just as boolean:

```
export class App {
  ...
  showHide: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.showHide = true;
  }
  ...
}
```

[Plunker: show/hide div with TS/Angular2](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y7hAyl02d5nhk2Rke3uO?p=preview)